# Получение значения элемента формы по name

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Я имею форму с инпутом, в котором `name="phone"`.
Как мне получить его в JS скрипте? Я знаю как получить по `id`, но мне это не подходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[name=phone]')
```

Answer (score 3):

Задаем форме имя

```
<form name="form">
    <input name="test" value="some" />
</form>
<script>
    alert(typeof form);//ооо... выяснилось что это объект
    alert(form.test.value);//даешь значение поля test
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('name');
var element = elements[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var name1=document.getElementsByName('phone');
// тут будет список всех элементов выбранных, нужно будет выбрать из массива нужный
```

Comment: getElementByName - такого метода не существует :)

Comment: Да ладно?

>Метод возвращает коллекцию элементов 
>страницы с заданным значением атрибута NAME.
>document.getElementByName("{Имя}");

Comment: @Shrek так может быть стоит отредактировать ответ?

Comment: поправил, я просто никогда им не пользовался в жизни, ей богу ни разу.

Comment: @Shrek - все-равно ошибка в коде т.к. getElementsByName возвращает NodeList. Иными словами, в вашем случае, name1 === udefined